# Edittext validation Only alpha characters and single word

Tags: android, android-edittext

`EditText` should only accept alpha characters and `EditText` should accept only  single word(space character also not allowed)

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: Want to validate edittext which should only accept characters i.e. (a-zA-Z), No Digits, No Space, No special characters.

Comment: Better to go through this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: improved formating

Answer (score 0):

Add this property in your edittext in xml :

```
  android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
```

and add a filter on your editText to manage the double space deleting issue :

```
InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {
            public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
                                       Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
                for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
                    if (Character.isWhitespace(source.charAt(i))) {
                        return "";
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }

        };
        editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter});
```

Comment: Not working for space character.(In some phone - OS version 5.0) If I clicked space twice then it is treating as backspace character. Last character of word is getting erased if I clicked space button twice.

Comment: do you want to allow using whitespace ?

Comment: No. I don't want to allow whitespace.  EditText should only accept single word **without** digits, special characters and whitespace.

Comment: updated answer. just add an input filter to handle the space key press.

Comment: @promod No. Still having issue for space character refer first comment